# How to remove rows related by name in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following records in a database table

```
ID   NAME         REF
-----------------------
1    ar.chik       33
4    ar.chik.rt    33
5    dy.i.op       35
9    dy.i
```

Which statement can remove the following records:

```
ID   NAME         REF
------------------------
4    ar.chik.rt    33
5    d.yi.op       35
```

Comment: What is the logic behind returning these rows as opposed to the others?

Comment: These rows are doubles with perfix (.rt, .op, etc). These are the duplicates I need to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete the rows in your table that are similar to the original `name`, then you should be able to use something similar to the following:

```
delete 
from yourtable
where id in (select id
             from
             (
               select id, 
                 row_number() over(partition by ref
                                   order by length(name)) rn
               from yourtable
             ) d
             where rn > 1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a12c/15)

Answer (score 1):

If I understanded what You want, You can Use this:

```
DELETE FROM Yourtable WHERE name='ar.chik.rt' OR name='d.yi.op' ;
```

or

```
DELETE FROM Yourtable WHERE name IN ('ar.chik.rt','d.yi.op') ;
```

Or if You want to remove the records with multiple dots:

```
DELETE FROM Yourtable WHERE name LIKE '%.%.%' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from Yourtable 
where id in(4,5);
```